# How to resize a plot object with various plotting functions?

Tags: plotting

I use `ContourPlot`,`PolarPlot`,`Graph` to plot. For example:

```
ContourPlot[x^2/3 + y^2/9 == 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
   PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion->1]
```

I get plot like:
[image]

I want this plot object to be 2 times bigger, then

```
ContourPlot[(0.5x)^2/3+(0.5*y)^2/9 == 1, {x, -10, 10},{y, -10, 10},
  PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

get plot as my will:

[image]

But my method is primitive. What's a better general method that can be used for various plot functions?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ScalingTransform](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingTransform.html) on the graphics primitives:

```
ClearAll[resize]
resize[sc_] :=  MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ScalingTransform[sc]] &, #, {1}] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
cp = ContourPlot[x^2/3 + y^2/9 == 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{cp, resize[{3, 3}] @ cp}]
```

[image]

```
pp = PolarPlot[Sin[3 t], {t, 0, Pi}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All,
    PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{pp, resize[{3, 3}] @ pp}]
```

[image]

For a `Graph` object `gr`, you need first wrap `gr` with `Show` to get a `Graphics` object before using `resize` on it:

```
gr = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3,  3 -> 1}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{gr, resize[{3, 3}] @ Show @ gr}]
```

[image]

For 3D plots use a list with three numbers, one for each dimension, as the scaling parameter:

```
cp3d = ContourPlot3D[Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z] == 0, {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}, {z, -π,  π}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4 π, 4 π}, {-4 π, 4 π}, {-4 π, 4 π}}, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{cp3d, resize[{2, 3, 3}] @ cp3d}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == f^2,
  {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
  PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[x^2/"a"^2 + y^2/"b"^2 == "f"^2]],
 {{a, Sqrt[3], "x control (a)"}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 3, "y control (b)"}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{f, 1, "scale (f)"}, .25, 3, .05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The `f^2` above resulted from dividing both `x` and `y` by `f` and simplifying the equation by multiplying through by `f^2`. In general, scaling all `x` and `y` by `f` won't produce a simple `f^2` factor but you still want to divide all of the occurrences of `x` and `y` by `f`.

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[
  (x/f)^(3/2) - Sqrt[1.65]*(x/f) + (y/f)^2 == 0,
  {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}],
 {{f, 1, "scale (f)"}, 1, 12, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: If the object is not ellipse,this method doesn't work.

Comment: @kittygirl - so what implicit equation is causing a problem?

Comment: ,`ContourPlot[
Power[(x), 3/2] - Power[1.65, 0.5]*(x) + ((y))^2 == 
 0, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
MaxRecursion -> 1]`,for more complex objects, we cannot resize them just by `f^2`